# how to add a check in Java code for fetching only non-negative values from result-set

Tags: java

In my Java code I have embedded a SQL query which fetches data from a database and stores it in a **result-set**. I want to add a function or a piece of code which will take only non-negative data from the result-set for further processing.

Assumption: The result set can contain positive/negative/zero data values as well as characters. Also i cannot change the SQL query as its out of my scope.

Comment: I think you should tweak your SQL query to fetch only positive values. It would be better there than in Java.

Comment: `WHERE foo > 0 and bar > 0 ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this, i think it will do the job

```
  private ArrayList getNegativeNumbers(ResultSet rs, String coulumnName ) throws SQLException
  { 
    ArrayList ret = new ArrayList();
    while(rs.next()){
      try {
        int x = rs.getInt(coulumnName);
        if(x>=0){
          ret.add(new Integer(x));
        }
      } catch (Exception ex) {
          String x = rs.getString(coulumnName);
          ret.add(x);
      } 
    }
    return ret;
  }
```

**UPDATED 2**. Sorry for my edits, i missread the question

Answer (score 0):

```
while (resultSet.next()) {

      if(resultSet.getInt("Column name") > 0);                       
      Processmethod(resultSet.getInt("Column name") );

     }
```